# Dashcode widget for displaying HTML

Tags: javascript, html, widget, dashcode

I need a Dashcode widget to display basic HTML like

```
<img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/AiQJ6.png"><i><b> 5 bronze badges</b></i></img>
```

Result: [image] ***5 bronze badges***

It should be something like a text label, but modifiable by JS code.

Comment: Any HTML/CSS/JS that works in safari works within a widget. So have you tried anything yet ?

Comment: tried html with a label - the tags show up - not working

Comment: the label showed the HTML code as raw text

Answer (score 0, accepted):

own answer - found it:

```
document.getElementById("label").innerHTML = '<img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/AiQJ6.png"><b><i> 5 bronze badges</b></i></img>';
```

Comment: You have nested the tags incorrectly <b><i> 5 bronze badges</b></i> when they should be <b><i> 5 bronze badges </i></b> and you can end the imc with /> rather than </img>